# How to use mobile data service while WiFi is connected?

Tags: android, networking

I am developing a test app that must be able to choose either WiFi or Mobile for data service. The following code shows both WiFi and Mobile networks are connected, but bindProcessToNetwork() fails on Mobile network.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConnectivityManager mConnMgr = null;
    private Network mNetworkWiFi = null;
    private Network mNetworkMobile = null;

    mConnMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean isWifiConn = false;
    boolean isMobileConn = false;
    for (Network network : mConnMgr.getAllNetworks()) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = mConnMgr.getNetworkInfo(network);

        if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
            mNetworkWiFi = network;
        }
        if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
            mNetworkMobile = network;
        }
    }

    if (mNetworkMobile && mConnMgr.getNetworkInfo(mNetworkMobile).isConnected()) {
        if (true != mConnMgr.bindProcessToNetwork(mNetworkMobile)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to bind to Mobile");
        }
    }
```

Questions:
1. Is bindProcessToNetwork() the correct way to select data service between WiFi and Mobile?
2. What could have caused bindProcessToNetwork() to fail on a connected Mobile network?

Comment: I am able to use Mobile data service while WiFi is connected with the following code:

Answer (score 0):

The following code lets me use MObile data service while WiFi is connected:

```
                final NetworkRequest networkReq = new NetworkRequest.Builder().addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET).addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR).build();
                mConnMgr.requestNetwork(networkReq, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Requested netwwork available: " + network.toString());
                        if (true != mConnMgr.bindProcessToNetwork(network)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to bind to Mobile");
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I am getting false returned when trying to bindProcessToNetwork - any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: The issue in my comment above was because I didn't have the Internet permission specified in my manifest.